# Why does refresh materialised view concurrently block inserts/updates?

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design

For this question's sake lets assume that the materialized view is with a two table join.

Refreshing this view concurrently blocks all updates/inserts.This is to ensure that when refreshing the view the data is up to date.

But why can't we allow updates/inserts when doing this,there is going to be updates anyway after doing the refresh and let the updates/inserts done during the refresh can reflect in the next time we refresh it.

What exactly is the design decision by blocking inserts/updates ? Am I missing something here ?

Comment: "*Refreshing this view concurrently blocks all updates/inserts*" - are you sure? I can't find anything in the manual that states this (assuming you are talking about inserts in the _source_ tables)

Comment: From the documentation [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/explicit-locking.html), an exclusive lock is acquired by refresh materialized view concurrently, that lock conflicts will all others except concurrent reads.The vice versa of that is my question.

Comment: The lock is acquired on the **materialized view**, not on the source tables.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : Yeah..the documentation confused me...I just tried it out and it does not acquire any exclusive lock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a subtle one.

It locks the *materialized view its self*. Not the tables it references; they are not locked against writes and may continue to be used normally.

`REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY` allows the refresh to proceed without preventing `SELECT`s on the view while it is being updated, per [the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-refreshmaterializedview.html). It can also perform better when updating a small portion of a big view.

Comment: Ah!! The documentation confused me a bit..thanks for clearing that up.